# What is the scope of the lock?

Tags: c#, locking

I've seen this piece of code [from one of the jetbrain's team](https://twitter.com/ivaduke/status/548106977742950400) :

Looking at this code :

```
object myLock = new object()

public IEnumerable<int> Values()
{
 lock (myLock)
 {
   for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
     yield return i;
 }
}



public void Test()
{
 foreach (var value  in Values())
  {
    DoHugeJob(value);   
  }
}


void Main()
{
    Test();
}
```

**Question:**

What is the scope of the `lock`?

Comment: Are you asking about lock or myLock?

Comment: @bit lock...... mylock is a field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean in terms of time - the lock will be aquired when `MoveNext()` is first called, and will be released *either* when `MoveNext()` has been called for the 11th time (i.e. when the loop completes) *or* when the iterator is disposed.

For example:

```
var iterable = Values();
// Lock is *not* acquired yet...

foreach (var item in iterable.Take(5)) {
    // Lock has been acquired
}
// Lock has been released even though we didn't get to the
// end of the loop, because foreach calls Dispose
```

In general it's a bad idea to lock in iterator blocks precisely because of this - you really want to lock for a short, easily-understood period of your program.